# Fixed Position for an DIV Element (Menu)

Tags: css, overflow

I want a fixed position for my left menu if i scroll down. But it didn't work: http://test.nooon.de/

Is it better to post the whole CSS and HTML Code here or to post just the link to the active (test)-site?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Spielwiese</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="background-image"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 nav">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-11 content">
      <p>
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. Seit 1975 fehlen in den meisten Testtexten die Zahlen, weswegen nach TypoGb. 204 § ab dem Jahr 2034 Zahlen in 86 der Texte zur Pflicht werden. Nichteinhaltung wird mit bis zu 245 € oder 368 $ bestraft. Genauso wichtig in sind mittlerweile auch Âçcèñtë, die in neueren Schriften aber fast immer enthalten sind. Ein wichtiges aber schwierig zu integrierendes Feld sind OpenType-Funktionalitäten. Je nach Software und Voreinstellungen können eingebaute Kapitälchen, Kerning oder Ligaturen (sehr pfiffig) nicht richtig dargestellt werden.Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks
        Dies ist ein Typoblindtext. An ihm kann man sehen, ob alle Buchstaben da sind und wie sie aussehen. Manchmal benutzt man Worte wie Hamburgefonts, Rafgenduks oder Handgloves, um Schriften zu testen. Manchmal Sätze, die alle Buchstaben des Alphabets enthalten - man nennt diese Sätze »Pangrams«. Sehr bekannt ist dieser: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy old dog. Oft werden in Typoblindtexte auch fremdsprachige Satzteile eingebaut (AVAIL® and Wefox™ are testing aussi la Kerning), um die Wirkung in anderen Sprachen zu testen. In Lateinisch sieht zum Beispiel fast jede Schrift gut aus. Quod erat demonstrandum. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#background-image {
  background: url("http://www.hkepci.com/data/out/22/338804-mountain-images.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #8391a9;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8391a9 0%, #788397 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8391a9), color-stop(100%, #788397));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8391a9 0%, #788397 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8391a9 0%, #788397 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8391a9 0%, #788397 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8391a9 0%, #788397 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#000000", GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  /* fallback if needed */
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 90%;
  /* fallback if needed */
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .nav {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4b555d;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 110px;
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00e4ff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00e4ff 0%, #00f0ff 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #00e4ff), color-stop(100%, #00f0ff));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00e4ff 0%, #00f0ff 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00e4ff 0%, #00f0ff 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00e4ff 0%, #00f0ff 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00e4ff 0%, #00f0ff 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#000000", GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .content {
  padding: 40px;
}
#wrapper .container-fluid .row .content p {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

#wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

CodePen:
    https://codepen.io/pauernet/pen/LQxxZR

i hope now i did everything alright. hope you can help. thank you very much.

greetings.

Comment: You should create a [mcve] - so not all the code, but only the minimal and necessary one. So go [edit] your question and use the `<>` Snippet tool to create one.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must include code in the question itself, do not ignore the rules of SO or try to bypass them by highlighting the link as code

Comment: i dont get it? i have to post html AND css code and then the codepen or jsfiddle link?

Is there an manual for that with examples for the future? 

Sorry but english is not my native language and its hard for me to understand everything. Thanks for your help here. I want to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to go trough all your lines, I think it's easier for you to go trough this couple ones.

So, here's a minimal essential code.
Don't make your wrapper scrollable, only the area you actually want to scroll:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; left:0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  max-width: 1400px;
}

#menu {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0bf;
  float: left;
}

#scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="menu">
    menu
  </div>

  <div id="scroll">
    <p style="border:4px dashed #000;height:200vh;">Long content...</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```css
ul{
  position:fixed;
  top:25px;
}

ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
  padding-top:20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid green;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

p{
  width:530px;
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left:150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT</li>
  <li>CONTACT</li>
  <li>REGISTER</li>
</ul>

<p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore quas officiis fuga, quos vel. Amet atque provident nisi rerum id ullam, officiis reprehenderit, dignissimos quidem doloremque cum magni nam!</span>
  <span>Eius, libero quos accusantium odit ad amet possimus vero officiis, maxime delectus sapiente consequatur iure, laudantium qui. Dicta, tempora quaerat accusamus, eaque eveniet, facilis ratione sed unde commodi vitae non?</span>
  <span>Perspiciatis possimus in officia, tenetur totam, deserunt error magnam, tempora at cupiditate ex sunt illo, quod ipsum maxime dolor. Reiciendis illum cum voluptas porro nesciunt dicta illo delectus qui dolor.</span>
  <span>Voluptate sunt tenetur quisquam ex, saepe, perferendis accusantium delectus ad harum minus libero quae vitae! Necessitatibus sapiente magni, hic unde quam natus tempora itaque est repudiandae modi facilis, praesentium ab.</span>
  <span>Dicta rem veniam laudantium, est nesciunt, esse! Reprehenderit sunt consequatur et sint ex velit dolor obcaecati, est, dicta iste eaque dolore. Ea tempora illum voluptatibus adipisci commodi unde animi eius!</span>
  <span>Quaerat, architecto. Maxime libero, nostrum minus, quam maiores corporis aliquam temporibus odit omnis porro! Vero magni consequatur voluptatum rerum corrupti placeat harum dolor eum, quaerat asperiores amet quas nesciunt aliquid.</span>
  <span>Dicta nesciunt pariatur deserunt quo! Explicabo tenetur, quod illo. Rem consequatur nesciunt rerum, recusandae porro perspiciatis aspernatur obcaecati, laboriosam veniam sapiente autem deserunt non distinctio repellendus, quasi assumenda mollitia tenetur.</span>
  <span>Vel distinctio molestiae, itaque qui rerum nulla temporibus ea molestias dolor voluptas fuga, recusandae odio officiis neque totam. Cumque, praesentium, asperiores. Earum eius consequatur eligendi rem, cupiditate cumque nostrum neque.</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore quas officiis fuga, quos vel. Amet atque provident nisi rerum id ullam, officiis reprehenderit, dignissimos quidem doloremque cum magni nam!</span>
  <span>Eius, libero quos accusantium odit ad amet possimus vero officiis, maxime delectus sapiente consequatur iure, laudantium qui. Dicta, tempora quaerat accusamus, eaque eveniet, facilis ratione sed unde commodi vitae non?</span>
  <span>Perspiciatis possimus in officia, tenetur totam, deserunt error magnam, tempora at cupiditate ex sunt illo, quod ipsum maxime dolor. Reiciendis illum cum voluptas porro nesciunt dicta illo delectus qui dolor.</span>
  <span>Voluptate sunt tenetur quisquam ex, saepe, perferendis accusantium delectus ad harum minus libero quae vitae! Necessitatibus sapiente magni, hic unde quam natus tempora itaque est repudiandae modi facilis, praesentium ab.</span>
  <span>Dicta rem veniam laudantium, est nesciunt, esse! Reprehenderit sunt consequatur et sint ex velit dolor obcaecati, est, dicta iste eaque dolore. Ea tempora illum voluptatibus adipisci commodi unde animi eius!</span>
  <span>Quaerat, architecto. Maxime libero, nostrum minus, quam maiores corporis aliquam temporibus odit omnis porro! Vero magni consequatur voluptatum rerum corrupti placeat harum dolor eum, quaerat asperiores amet quas nesciunt aliquid.</span>
  <span>Dicta nesciunt pariatur deserunt quo! Explicabo tenetur, quod illo. Rem consequatur nesciunt rerum, recusandae porro perspiciatis aspernatur obcaecati, laboriosam veniam sapiente autem deserunt non distinctio repellendus, quasi assumenda mollitia tenetur.</span>
  <span>Vel distinctio molestiae, itaque qui rerum nulla temporibus ea molestias dolor voluptas fuga, recusandae odio officiis neque totam. Cumque, praesentium, asperiores. Earum eius consequatur eligendi rem, cupiditate cumque nostrum neque.</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span><span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
  <span>Ab aliquam eveniet laudantium temporibus veniam voluptate dignissimos itaque repellendus nulla dolor dolorem, optio facilis quaerat eum incidunt libero a rem eius nam saepe sunt. Commodi magni fugiat voluptate quaerat!</span>
</p>
```